# Vuepress Randomized Component Name

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuepress

I was working on a project with Vuepress when suddenly, for seemingly no reason, things stopped loading. Additionally, my palette.styl folder partially stopped working. For reference, all colors within it worked but `$contentWidth = 90%` stopped and turned into 100%.

What do I mean by "stopped loading":
An initial page will load up, with the odd content width setting. This is annoying in itself, however when I attempt to change my page (Via sidebar) VuePress attempts to load a random component rather than page content.

Example Error (The component names are randomized, so each is different):

```
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <v-196ea192> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

---> <Content>
       <Page> at node_modules/@vuepress/theme-default/components/Page.vue
         <Layout> at node_modules/@vuepress/theme-default/layouts/Layout.vue
           <GlobalLayout> at AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/vuepress/node_modules/@vuepress/core/lib/client/components/GlobalLayout.vue
             <Root>
```

Example #2

```
vue.runtime.esm.js?9205:619 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <v-6185cf16> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

---> <Content>
       <Page> at node_modules/@vuepress/theme-default/components/Page.vue
         <Layout> at node_modules/@vuepress/theme-default/layouts/Layout.vue
           <GlobalLayout> at AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/vuepress/node_modules/@vuepress/core/lib/client/components/GlobalLayout.vue
             <Root>
```

Oddly enough, I am not using any components in the files I am attempting to use. This has lead me to an incredible amount of confusion, and any attempts to help would be greatly appreciated. If anymore information is needed, please feel free to ask for it.